# Simulate an attack while+array+objects

Tags: php

```
class Gunner {

    public $health;
    public $attack;

    function __construct($health, $attack) {
        $this->health = $health;
        $this->attack = $attack;
    }
}

$player = array();
$player[] = new Gunner(100, 20);
$player[] = new Gunner(100, 20);
$player[] = new Gunner(100, 20);

$enemy = array();
$enemy[] = new Gunner(100, 20);
$enemy[] = new Gunner(100, 20);
```

I want to have some while loop that run through as long as the both arrays has "entities" / objects. How do I do that?
I want to fight each and every entity, like $player[0] would be fighting (aka do a rand(1,20)) and then remove from the opposites health until its 0. And when its 0 or less I  would remove the entity (object) from the array.

I am not sure how the while loop or the delete from array would look like.

```
while ((count($attacker) > 0) && (count($defender) > 0))
{
    $attacker_attack = rand(1, 25);

    $defender[0]->health -= $attacker_attack;

    if (!$defender[0]->IsAlive()) {
        unset($defender[0]);
        array_values($defender);
    }

    $defender_attack = rand(1, 20);

    $attacker[0]->health -= $defender_attack;

    if (!$attacker[0]->IsAlive()) {
        unset($attacker[0]);
        array_values($attacker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not you start learning programming from some **basic** tasks?

Comment: Because I am note quite sure how to do THIS in php in particular, Sure, I could come up with some bad , ugly solution on it, but I want the best approach?

Comment: I am using using count() to get the number of objects (array elements) and then I run the while loop as long as there are more than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this ([demo](http://codepad.org/YVBqDSeN))?

```
class Gunner
{
    public $health;
    public $attack;

    public function __construct($health, $attack)
    {
        $this->health = $health;
        $this->attack = $attack;
    }
}

$attacker = array
(
    new Gunner(100, 20),
    new Gunner(100, 20),
    new Gunner(100, 20),
);

$defender = array
(
    new Gunner(100, 30),
    new Gunner(100, 30),
);

while ((count($attacker) > 0) && (count($defender) > 0)) // fight till death!
{
    $defender[0]->health -= $attacker[0]->attack;

    if ($defender[0]->health <= 0) // defender dead?
    {
        unset($defender[0]); $defender = array_values($defender);
    }

    if (count($defender) > 0) // are any def alive for counter-attack?
    {
        $attacker[0]->health -= $defender[0]->attack;

        if ($attacker[0]->health <= 0) // attacker dead?
        {
            unset($attacker[0]); $attacker = array_values($attacker);
        }
    }
}

print_r($attacker);
print_r($defender);
```

**PS:** I updated the code to reflect your last comment, it's kinda unclear how the turns should be played.

Comment: I believe the best would be to let each player/enemy attack one per time

Comment: @John: That's what I meant when I said you're being unclear. I suppose you know how to change that?

Comment: I updated my post with my pseudo code, that i did before the question... (but with your while statement instead) what do you think...

Comment: @John: I think that `array_values()` isn't doing anything, `unset()` doesn't work because `array_values()` isn't returning anything, and I really don't get the `rand(1, 25)` and `rand(1, 20)`, should't that come from `Gunner::$attack`? Also, a `Gunner::attack()` method would make things more logical.

Comment: @John: Also, your problem could be solved in a mathematical way without the need for loops.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem with array_values. The rand(1,25) is just pseudo code, I am trying to just get started

How can it be solved?

Comment: @John: I'm too lazy to figure out the equation now, but I'm sure it can be done using the attack and health properties of both entities. http://codepad.org/5mRpV6ZA where does `rand()` come into this?

Comment: Yeah I think the best way would be to have some sort of equation because If there are look 2000 entities it would take some time, am I right? (Too loop through)

I actually asked a Math teacher and he told me to count all the different attributes (as attack, defence, health, etc) and then the ones with greater "stats" would win, the problem would be to know which soldiers on the winning side, would survive.

Comment: @John: If the health of all soldiers on the winning side is the same (eg. 100), you just need let `floor($result / 100)` soldiers with full life and another one with `$result % 100` life (possibly 0).

Comment: Well the thing is there will be more different types of soldiers with different health, there will also be more stats than those 2 mentioned, this was just pseudo, basically I had 2 different methods 1 loop through all entities, 2) equation, i realized that the method one wouldn't work in the length

Comment: @John: Makes sense, sorting will define the outcome then.